# Delphi deployment and Android file storage

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe7

If I try to deploy a file to deployment *assets\internal\assets.zip* and *assets.zip* like this:
[image]

I have tried all sorts of paths to see if I could locate the assets folder or my zip file. All of underneath code is unsuccessful at doing so

```
  S1 := TPath.GetHomePath + PathDelim;
  S2 := FAppDataDirPathRoot + Application.Title + '.app' + PathDelim;
  S3 := TPath.GetLibraryPath + PathDelim;
  S4 := TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim;

  if (DirectoryExists(S1)) then // '/data/data/com.embarcadero.xxx/files/': yes:
    msAppNoOp
  ;
  if (DirectoryExists(S2)) then // ...: no, leftover test from iOS
    msAppNoOp
  ;
  if (DirectoryExists(S3)) then // '/data/app-lib/com.embarcadero.xxx-2/': yes
    msAppNoOp
  ;
  if (DirectoryExists(S4)) then // '/data/data/com.embarcadero.xxx/files/' yes
    msAppNoOp
  ;

  if (DirectoryExists(S1 + 'assets' + PathDelim)) then // no
    msAppNoOp
  ;
  if (DirectoryExists(S2 + 'assets' + PathDelim)) then // no
    msAppNoOp
  ;
  if (DirectoryExists(S3 + 'assets' + PathDelim)) then // no
    msAppNoOp
  ;
  if (DirectoryExists(S4 + 'assets' + PathDelim)) then // no
    msAppNoOp
  ;

  S1 := S1 + 'assets.zip';
  S2 := S2 + 'assets.zip';
  S3 := S3 + 'assets.zip';
  S4 := S4 + 'assets.zip';


  if (FileExists(S1)) then // no
    msAppNoOp
  ;
  if (FileExists(S2)) then // no
    msAppNoOp
  ;
  if (FileExists(S3)) then // no
    msAppNoOp
  ;
  if (FileExists(S4)) then // no
    msAppNoOp
  ;
```

When browsing my phone in Windows Explorer I can not see *data/data/...* which I believe is only possible rooted phones...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Creating_an_Android_App#Loading_and_Deploying_Files), if you deploy to `assets/internal` then you need to use `TPath.GetDocumentsPath` to get the folder where the deployed file exists at runtime.  Try using `TPath.Combine()` instead of using `PathDelim` directly:

```
S4 := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'assets.zip');
if (FileExists(S4)) then
```

Comment: Thanks - it appears to work now. Not quite sure how I could create a  series of tests which did not result in a solution :)